# Unable to host Django app on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have built a django app and its working fine in local machine, I tried hosting it in Google Cloud Platform.

1. Created a project Google Console
2. Created a django VM Instance
3. I cloned the repo from bitbucket
4. Installed all the dependencies
5. Created a database and made sure same credentials are used in settings.py
6. python manage.py syncdb - this is executed
7. Python manage.py collectstatic - this is executed

When I created a VM Instance I was given a dedicated IP, there is already a app called Project. I cloned the repo beside this folder (this is the IP https://130.211.79.74 and this is the link to the default app https://130.211.79.74/Project). I tried accessing my app and I see a 404 error. Is there anything that am missing.

Comment: I tried accessing my app with this url https://130.211.79.74/sfdctube and I see a 404 error. Is there anything that am missing.

Screens
http://bit.ly/19Y1LHv
http://bit.ly/1D5v1cd
http://bit.ly/1ICXox0
http://bit.ly/1D5v8EE

Comment: are you sure it's a 404, IMHO, it's an incorrectly setup https. http://130.211.79.74/ seems to work fine (http not https)

Comment: Yeah its showing 404 error. The app I hosted it sfdctube, so the url will be something like http://130.211.79.74/sfdctube/. Because default app url is http://130.211.79.74/Project/. These two folders are side by side. @RaphaëlBraud

Comment: I assumed it's an urls.py issue, is there a pattern for sfdctube in your urls.py ? In Django, it's not the folder's hierarchy that defines the urls

Comment: did you try moving your code in Project folder (it there is one ?)

Comment: This is the url pattern - 
`url(r'^', include('app.urls')),`

in app/urls.py

`url(r'^$', views.index),`

Even if there is a problem I was expecting the django specific page not found error screen not the standard 404 error

Comment: and what does app/urls.py look like ?

Comment: No I didn't tried moving sfdctube folder into project folder, coz Project folder itself is a Django project. Hence I moved sfdctube folder beside Project folder and thought the url pattern is ipaddress/foldername gives the landing page.

Comment: Project itself is a Django project but isn't it an example project ?

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/krishnateja/9f94f4db7e69481cb51d) this is how the urls.py looks like

Comment: ok, so, sfdctube is not an url. it's not a Django related issue, it's a Google cloud, configuration issue, check in your Google django project parameters to change your project root to use 'sfdctube' instead of 'Project'

Comment: This is how the folder structure is [link](http://i.imgur.com/k6Lr35a.png?1)

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud - Sure will do that. Thank you so much for your inputs.

Comment: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_Django_Stack  --  I followed this and made changes to wsgi.py and some other conf files. Even then I get the same error any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I tried curl 130.211.79.74, and it shows 200 OK.
I tried curl 130.211.79.74/Project, and it shows 404 Not Found.
I tried curl 130.211.79.74/sfdctube, and it shows 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the good paths in your wsgi.py file :

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('installdir/apps/django/django_projects/my_new_project')
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE", "installdir/apps/django/django_projects/my_new_project/egg_cache")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_new_project.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Don't forget** to reload Apache so that your modifications are taken into account.

Comment: When I try restarting the Apache server like this 

`sudo /opt/bitnami/apache2 restart` I see this
**sudo: /opt/bitnami/apache2: command not found**

I think the path to Apache2 is something am messing up with as far as reloading the server is concerned. Is there anything that am missing.

Comment: `apachectl -k restart` - this worked for me in restarting apache2.

Comment: Yeah reloading the server took me a step ahead and now am stuck at `ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: libpq.so
.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: In your settings.py file, it seems you're using a PostgreSQL backend but libpq is not installed <=> you'll need to install PostgreSQL package and PostgreSQL dev package. Installation depends on underlying distribution